# Delay differential equations in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the delay differential equation given by

```
x'(t)=1-x(t)-x(t+2) if 0<= t <=2
      1-x(t)        if 2<  t <=4,
```

where `x(4)=0` in Mathematica. I have already solved by hand and I obtained the solution

```
x(t)=e^(2-t)*(t-1-e^2) if 0<= t <=2
     1-e^(4-t)         if 2<  t <=4.
```

I used the following code

```
solx2=DSolve[{x22'[t]==1-x22[t],x22[4]==0},x22[t],t]
x2[t_]=x22[t]/.solx2[[1]]
```

and I obtained the solution

`x2[t]=1-e^(4-t)` for `2 < t <= 4`. After I used the code

```
solx1=DSolve[{x11'[t]==1-x11[t]-x11[t+2],x11[t/;t>2]==x2[t+2]},x11[t],{t,0,2}]
```

and I obtained the message "**Part 1 of {} does not exist.**" Can somebody help me? I don't know why I don't obtain the solution that I obtained solving by hand.

Thanks!

---

Thank you so much! In this form it results :) I also tried to compute using a piecewise function, but I didn't have success, too.

More one question... I want to derivate the function

```
H(u)=-u^2-y^2 + u*eta[t+1] if 0<= t <=3 and H(u)=-u^2 if 3<  t <=4
```

in order to u and solving this derivative equal to zero, using the following code:

```
eta[t_]:=Piecewise[{{E^(2-t)*(-1-E^2+t),0 <= t <= 2},{1-E^(4-t),2 < t <= 4}}]

H[u_] := Piecewise[{{-u^2 - y^2 + u*eta[t+1], 0 <= t <= 3}, {-u^2, 3 < t <= 4}}]

uS = D[H[u], u]

uSS = Reduce[uS == 0, u]
```

I want so save the output of uSS as a function u(t). How I can do this without using the archaic form given by

```
u[t_] = Piecewise[{{uSS[[1, 2, 2]], uSS[[1, 1]]}, {uSS[[2, 2, 2]], uSS[[2, 1]]}, {uSS[[3, 2, 2]], uSS[[3, 1]]}}]
```

?

Thanks again!

Comment: I wonder if `DSolve` can handle the delay actually coming from the "future" (`t+2`) instead of the past.  Have you tried reversing `t` in your system?

Comment: I tried it with the past, it gives an output but still with the same error msg and a missing part.

Comment: Please do not ask questions in 'answers' place. Please take an effort to format your edits ('?' button on the top right corner). Do not ask multiple questions at once and if you want some quick, small adjustment, make sure it is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my comment, I defined a new "time" variable $\tau=4-t$ and substituted it along with $dt=-d\tau$ to get an equivalent "forward time" system $$dx/d\tau=\{x(\tau)-1,\tau<2; x(\tau)+x(\tau-2)-1,\tau>2\}$$ $$x(\tau=0)=0$$

Then `DSolve` works fine, following OP's approach:

```
DSolve[{x'[τ] == x[τ] - 1, x[0] == 0}, x, {τ, 0, 2}]
(* {{x -> Function[{τ}, 1 - E^τ]}} *)

sol = DSolve[{x'[τ] == x[τ] + x[τ - 2] - 1, x[τ /; τ < 2] == 1 - E^τ}, x,
  {τ, 2, 4}][[1]];
Simplify[x[τ] /. sol /. τ -> 4 - t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It would be nice to automate this transformation and to only use one `DSolve` on a `Piecewise`-defined function, but I couldn't get those to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is in the `x11[t+2]` part of the expression in the first equation shown.  Consider this simpler DE to solve:

```
DSolve[{x3’[t]==1-x3[t+2]},x3[t],{t,0,2}]
```

It returns the error message

> ```
> DSolve::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in {(x3^\[Prime])[t]==1-x3[2+t]} should literally match the independent variables.
> ```

The problem appears to be not formulated properly.

Also, substituting the answer given for the first eqn, obtained by hand, back into the first eqn doesn’t check.